# Can anyone explain How smart contract gets validated?

Tags: solidity, dapps

Is there any validation process of smart contract's write operations ?

Comment: Hi, I did not specifically understand your question. You can check out this link https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper for basics of Ethereum as well as how Ethereum is different from Bitcoin.

Comment: Thanks for your response @SanjaySB . I will go through that above link and will get clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All smart contracts are replicated across all nodes. And their code is part of a block, and therefore part of the block's hash value. So if you somehow 'hack' a smart contract in one node all other nodes would ignore the changes as they have the right version which produces the right hash value for the block.

Smart contract interactions are validated also in the same way: all transactions are replayed by all nodes so any strangeness in the interaction would be detected and ignored by all other nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Lauri Peltonen . Let's say there is a huge traffic to my dapp its around 1cr active nodes in my dapp. How much time it will take to validate by all 1 cr nodes for single transaction. ?

Comment: Your dapp doesn't have nodes. A node is simply used to communicate with the blockchain. A block can currently have about 8 million gas in it, so you can estimate how many blocks (at least) it requires for all the transactions to be processed by the network.

Comment: Got it and its clear explaition. Thank you @Lauri Peltonen